# Unity Windows metro app crashes randomly

Tags: unity-game-engine, microsoft-metro, windows-10-universal

Many users are complaining that at some point the game closes itself in the middle of the game.
Windows 10 Game is built using Unity 5.3.5.
In Microsoft dev console I see the following error thrown

> APPLICATION_HANG_QUIESCE_THROTTLED_PRELAUNCH_BusyHang_cfffffff_..

When I expand Stack Trace, it shows only this:

> outstanding_deferrals

I can't reproduce the crash on my side. Any idea on how to investigate this ?